# Using "doch" to invert a vaguely negative statement

Tags: grammar

I have learnt that one of the uses of the word "doch" is that it can be used to invert a negative statement. For instance:

> Hast du kein Geld?

We can reply:

> Doch! Ich habe Geld.

Or:

> Du hast das nicht gemacht?

Response:

> Doch! Ich habe das gemacht.

However, does the initial negative statement have to include "kein" or "nicht" to specifically indicate a negative statement? Or can "doch" be used to respond to negative statements that are implied?

E.g.

> Bist du knapp an Geld?

Could we respond with "Doch, Ich habe viel Geld"?

> Englisch finde ich sehr schwierig. Deutsch is einfacher.

Could we respond with "Doch, English ist einfacher!"?

Comment: The latter type doesn't work in German, the "nicht" or "kein" is essential. (And I have a hunch that we had this question before. Somewhere....)

Comment: Short answer: No, because they are not negative questions. Negativity is not understood in a context of good or bad, but rather in its grammatical way. e.g. »Bist du böse?« »Doch« … waitwot?